# eclipse dynamic web project doesn't generate classes WEB_INF folder

Tags: eclipse, class

I hava a Dynamic Web Project and when I clean the project classes aren't generated in WEB_INF folder. In the workspace, I have some projects with errors. My project doesn't have errors.

I configured the folder WEB_INF/classes

[image]

Screen with the folder WEB-INF classes

[image]

How can I generate the classes in WEB_INF folder?

Comment: Cleaning is not Building. Are you then Building? And the Package Explorer doesn't show class files built from your sources because your sources are the files you would work on. Use the Navigator View or filesystem to check if they're actually there.

Comment: I build the project in the Navigator view but the classes are not generated

Comment: .class files goes to the path defined in `Default output folder` under `<project> -> properties -> Java Build Path`.

Comment: Yeah, you wont see the generated classes in the project view but if you right click the project, go to properties, resources.  Get the path to the project on the file system, then go into the WEB-INF folder you class files should exist.  You can also export it as a WAR file, then open the WAR in a zip application, go to the WEB-INF folder and the classes should also exist there